# SQL When NOT to use an index

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table which keeps track of time slots for scheduling.  It's a record of "locks" so that 2 users would not book appointments in the same time slot.

We have a deadlock issue in production and I noticed that this table has 5 indexes.

This table is read and written frequently but it would rarely have more than a few hundred rows it.

5 indexes seems like overkill for me.  I don't think I need any indexes at all for a table with under 1000 rows.

Am I correct in that assumption?

TIA

Comment: deadlock issue has not relation with indexes. Be careful with group by and aggregation functions.

Comment: "deadlock issue has not relation with indexes" - not entirely correct...The 'right' indexes can often lead to less blocking...

Comment: @MitchWheat - Under what circumstances can indexes lead to dead-locks?

Comment: make sure the table has row-level locking turned on. some dbas are resistant to that.

Comment: @danihp - Under what circumstances can using GROUP BY and/or aggregation functions lead to dead-locks?

Comment: @MitchWheat, how can an index prevent deadlock (not blocking) in a 1k rows table?

Comment: @Dems - Under what circumstances can indexes lead to dead-locks? When 2 different transactions are using different indexes to find rows of interest this can increase probability of them acquiring same resources in different orders.

Comment: @dems, the tipical case is to do `max(id)+1` to calculate new id. This can block all rows in high isolation level (in no phantoms). Block all table has implications: If a session has entire tableA blocked and is waiting for a tableB row and another session has entire tableB blocked and is waiting for tableA row, then here is the deadlock.

Comment: Yes the issue is that this table is written and updated very frequently. If indexes are slowing down the updates (since there are 5 of them) it's more likely to cause a deadlock.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Is this not still a function of what order the code acquires resources, rather than the presence of indexes per-se?  *(In the same way that having more SPs, or more tables, create more potential dead-lock situations, but it's the code's acquisition of resources that is the proximate cause?)*

Comment: @DanHoward - A dead-lock isn't just one process waiting on another, a dead-lock is an unresolvable dependancy. Process1 is waiting for Process2 to release a resource, but Process2 is waiting for Process1 to release a resource. They will wait forever, therfor a deadlock. One solution is to ensure that all processes acquire those resources in the same order, as this will mean that each process will queue behind the other, rather than take different colliding routes.

Comment: @Dems Database should handle this situation itself. It's not unresolvable dependency like in regular application. Modern database detect and resolve it.

Comment: @Umar - Dead-locks are by definition unresolveable dependancies. They're "resolved" by killing one process. If process1 locks A then B, and process2 locks B then A, a race condition arises; Where Process has locked A, but not B, and process2 has locked B and not A. At this stage they are dead-locked. There is ***no*** resolution to this situation that allows both processes to complete.

Comment: @Dems And again, it's not about "race condition", concurrency issues and other liveness failure. It's database deadlock on row, table etc. Btw don't miss thread with proccesses.

Comment: @Umar - I don't know what you think a dead-lock is, but it certainly doesn't agree with any definition I know.  It is ***specifically*** a symptom caused by concurrent processes.  If there is only one active process then you ***can't*** have a dead-lock.

Comment: What RDBMS? What table structure including indexes? What are the queries that are deadlocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick, rule-of-thumb answer: drop all indexes except the unique index on the primary key, on relatively small tables (typically less than 100,000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

Indexes does not affect locking. Note, every write operation should change indexes as well. It could have some performance issue, but should not affect locking. If your table has only 1000 rows, you can drop your indexes. Iteration over log1000 is not much faster then iteration over 1000 rows.

```
This table is read and written frequently but it would rarely have more than a few hundred rows it.
```

Row locking is regular situation. Deadlock can happen sometimes too. Does your DB provider handle deadlock ? It should release it itself. Probably locking happens cause your try to update rows in order A,B in 1 transcation and second transaction updates rows in B,A order.

Comment: This table is using application level locking for scheduled resources. So I have an index on location + datetime. If 2 users are vying for this same appointment time and there's an index - I suspect that might be the cause of a conflict.  My sense is that 5 indexes is slowing down the write operations enough to cause that possible concurrency issue to occur more often.

Comment: For sure, write operation with 5 indexes is slower then operation without indexes. In theory if DB release lock it can reduce amount of dead-lock. But I don't think it's true. Try to drop indexes and test